# QGIS 3.14.1 not starting on my Laptop

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

[image: Qgis Pi Splashscreen]
After this QGIS doesn't start

[image: System config]
System config

When double click on QGIS Desktop 3.14.1 is shows the screen as attached but after that the program does not start or run. I have also tried "run as administrator" but still the problem persists. I also run the software with Internet connection ON but in vain. Once I was able to recover the crash file for v3.10 (attached herewith). With v3.10 and v3.14.1, same problem is occurring. I have tried to search the internet for various blogs, sites listed in your website support page, still no solution is there for my particular problem. I have installed software again with "Run as Administrator" but the issue is not solved.

.NET 4.8 already installed.

C++2005 to 2008 all are installed.

> Error for 3.10 Crash ID: 5c75d2351852793e7098138ee0f44da41b6fa5f4
>
> Stack Trace
>
> CleanupThreadTlsData : DllMain :
> _DllMainCRTStartup : LdrpCallInitRoutine : LdrShutdownThread : RtlExitUserThread : BaseThreadInitThunk : RtlUserThreadStart :
>
> QGIS Info QGIS Version: 3.10.7-A Coru�a QGIS code revision: 7b4ca4c8d0
> Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2 Running against Qt: 5.11.2 Compiled
> against GDAL: 3.0.4 Running against GDAL: 3.0.4
>
> System Info CPU Type: x86_64 Kernel Type: winnt Kernel Version:
> 10.0.18363

What to do?

Comment: Do you have more QGIS installed on your PC? Was there previously a QGIS 3.10 installed on your PC?

Comment: You might try renaming or deleting your QGIS user name folder: C:\Users\youruvernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS

Comment: @Taras No, currently QGIS 3.10 not installed on my PC. But previously I had it on system because It was stable version. But in that also the same problem was there. So i Installed v3.14.1. But program is not sarting.

Comment: @johns  Still the problem is same, after "setting up GUI" screen , program does not starts.

Comment: Did you use the Standalone Windows Installer or the OSGeo4W Network Installer from here: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html?  Whichever one you used you can always try the other.  They install into different folders and can co-exist, but if the second works you can uninstall the first.  If you haven't used the OSGeo4W you can go with the Express or you could select Advanced which might seem a bit daunting at first until you get familiar with it.

Comment: @johns , Thanks for upgrade. I have installed it with standalone installer. I will try the latter one.

Comment: @johns, still the same problem persists. I can't understand what is going wrong in standalone or webinstaller.

Comment: You might join and submit your problem to the QGIS users mailing list: https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user or look at bug reports https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

Comment: @johns . Thanks for the links and the advice. It one report i found answer about its local issue. Wonder now what to do. Might have to think about other freeware software. By the way, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Kaushik.  That's too bad.  Did you submit your problem to the user's list?  The QGIS installs do include SAGA which can be used as its own GIS program.  The same with GRASS.  You might also see if you can install and run QGIS in a virtual machine.